# Read HTML File in iFrame and Converted to PDF

Tags: iframe, c#-2.0

Below is my HTML File code

```
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPDF" runat="Server">
            <iframe type="application/pdf" src="up/waters 6form.pdf"
                width="956" height="500"></iframe>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

In this HTML there is a Fill-able PDF...
User enters data and submits.
when user submits I need to convert into PDF File.

assume that pdf file contains
Name: __________
Gender: __________

when user enters the detail...how to save as pdf

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's two issues: 
1. Transfering the data from the fillable PDF to the ASPX page. This is as trivial as changing the post to the aspx page.
2. Creating a PDF. This will take a little more work, and probably requires a third-party product like PDFSharp.

Alternatively, have you looked at FDF? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html